# Unable to save to nul device from ASP.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a spot of bother trying to save a dummy file to the nul device in an ASP.Net (.Net 4.5.2) application. When I get the the point where the application tries to save the file, it throws an exception.

The file's path is set to "nul" (sic), and when it is saved I get the following exception message:

```
Access denied to file "\\\\.\\nul"
```

Is it possible using .Net (C# in my case) to save a file to the nul device from within a web application?

In case you are wondering, saving the file is merely a trigger for another action. I am not interested in the saved file itself, and I want to avoid the code overhead of having to create and later delete a uniquely named dummy file - hence saving it to the nul device.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43163abb-4e82-4a7d-b614-29eb7914bdba/nul-filename-in-net#3fd5b832-a81c-4774-b6e9-f1edb8556517) answer on MSDN suggests you can't do this with the .NET file handling API:

> While the Win32 CreateFile method will open devices, alternate streams, etc, somewhere along the line it was decided that the .Net File implementation would be restricted to traditional files.  Probably not what you wanted to hear.

[social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43163abb-4e82-4a7d-b614-29eb7914bdba/nul-filename-in-net](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43163abb-4e82-4a7d-b614-29eb7914bdba/nul-filename-in-net)

Comment: No, not what I wanted to hear! But thanks for the info. I'd love to get my hands on whoever decided "somewhere along the line" to limit .Net file handling in this way. So inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

use the flag that deletes filestream on close...

```
new FileStream(TempFileName,
FileMode.CreateNew,
FileAccess.ReadWrite,
FileShare.ReadWrite, 512, 
FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```